# Is there some order for sorting the top reviewers of the day?

Tags: support, review, review-stats

Occasionally, I make it onto the "top reviewers of the day" list for a particular review queue.

But, as the day progresses, the ordering for people with the same number of reviews appears to change randomly.  Especially once many people have reached the maximum number of reviews for that queue.

The tie breaker doesn't seem to be the

- time of the reviews,
- reputation,
- number of total reviews,
- number of brown pixels in gravatar,
- alphabetical (by username),
- or any other metric I can think of.

How is this list sorted?  What is the tie-breaker for people with the same number of reviews?

Comment: My guess the sorting is random, and cached for a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today, January 10th 2019, there *is* an explicit, secondary order for the "Today" list: reviewers with the same number of reviews will be ordered according to the time at which each person last reviewed - so each new person to hit the limit will rise to the top of the list in turn, giving everyone a chance of recognition.

Kudos to Nick Craver for this idea, which he implemented today while assisting Taryn with [some much-needed performance improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322183/review-spring-cleaning-performance-improvements-and-responsive-design) to the review stats pages.