# Equal reviewing stats causing other reviewers to be pushed of the list. How is it ordered?

Tags: support

My issue is, looking at the reviewing stats 4 hours before they are reset, everyone on the top reviewers list is  on the maximum 20 reviews.

[image]

So why is it that I'm not on the list? I was on the list earlier today/yesterday once I'd finished my 20, and it appears I have been pushed off the list. Why does the list not extend if everyone is equal? And how is it ranked? As far as I can tell, it's not by latest done, as dreamcrash:

[image]

Finished his 20 after me.

I had a look around for posts on the topic, and came up with [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161153/is-there-some-order-for-sorting-the-top-reviewers-of-the-day), however, there doesn't appear to be an answer.

Edit: to make clear, however similar the question may seem to the questions this was marked duplicate of, **neither of those questions have answers**, which is exactly why I brought this question to light again.

Comment: ...why does it matter? [status-bydesign]?

Comment: @doorknob, I just can't see any logic in the ordering, and I would very much like to know whether, for example, if it is effected by review quality or some such.

Comment: I *think* its ordered by reputation if your review counts are equal.

Comment: @raghavSood, nope, I don't think that's the case, it's seemingly random.

Comment: If you think the question doesn't have any answer (or sufficient answer) then asking the same question is not the way to bring that question in light. Instead start [a bounty](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) on that question.

Comment: @hims056, I don't particularly want to lose a whole bunch of privileges, so I never considered starting a bounty. Besides, when I posted this question, I didn't actually have enough rep to post a bounty. Besides, the duplicate notification specifies to edit the question or ask a new one, *not* start a bounty.