# How are users ranked in the review system?

Tags: support, reputation, review-stats, rankings

How are people ranked on [this first post stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats) for example?

- Are they ranked on directly on the basis of how many question/answers they review?
- Are they rank based on the time(the user who completed 20 review tasks first will be placed first)?
- The users are ranked on the basis of short time required by them to review a question/an answer?
- As in the reputation league the users with highest reputation and top review combined are displayed first,second,third and so on?

Comment: see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161153/is-there-some-order-for-sorting-the-top-reviewers-of-the-day)

Comment: @Azik it doesn't have an answer there it has only comments,btw thanks